# What is a fastest way to manage MySQL data? pandas vs fetch_row

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pandas, mysql-python

I was wondering what is the common and the better way to manage data, that I recieve from MySQL.

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="####", user="####", passwd="####", db="####", charset='utf8')
db.query(sql)
result = db.use_result()
```

I use use_result() because data is pretty big (about 9000000 lines) and I don't have much RAM.

After that I'm working with this data line per line by

```
line = result.fetch_row(maxrows=1, how=1)[0]
#creating objects from lines
```

But I found another way to manage MySQL data by using a pandas DataFrame

```
df = pd.read_sql_query('SQL QUERY', con= db)
```

So the question is simple - what is better?

P.S. I can't really test what is faster on my cheap laptop, because the execution time this program is fluctuating from 170 to 250 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Test it on a smaller data-set.

The performance would be the same given you do not test using extremely small sets of data.